# how to change xml node value in Jscript?

Tags: xml, jscript, xmldom

I need to change  node value with today's date using jscript

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<scraping Test>
    <General>
        <FormatVersion>1</FormatVersion>
        <FromDate>2/28/2019 00:00:00</FromDate>
        <ToDate>2/28/2019</ToDate>
    </General>
</scraping Test>
```

Jscript (tried using 2 methods)

```
var dom = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
pathToXML = "Y:\Analysis33.xml"  ;
dom.loadxml(pathToXML);
mydate = date(); 
myVar1 = mydate & " 00:00:00" ; 
myVar2 = mydate ;

nNode = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("FromDate")    ;
nNode.text = myvar1 ;
strResult = xmldoc.save(pathtoxml) ;
```

I have tried MSXML2.DOM also similar code, but did not work.

```
var objXML = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
```

Answer (score 0):

Biggest problem is your XML is invalid and unparseable by any recipe of JScript sorcery until you fix it.  Get rid of the illegal space in your `<scraping Test>` tag.  Make it `<scrapingTest>` or `<root>`.

You also need to select the `text()` node in your XPath, then modify the resulting node's `.data` property.

Other than that, fix all the cAmElCaSe disagreement in your code and get your date formatting under control.  Using this XML:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<scrapingTest>
    <General>
        <FormatVersion>1</FormatVersion>
        <FromDate>2/28/2019 00:00:00</FromDate>
        <ToDate>2/28/2019</ToDate>
    </General>
</scrapingTest>
```

This code works for me to parse and modify it:

```js
var dom = WSH.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0"),
    pathToXML = WSH.Arguments(0);

dom.load(pathToXML);

var nNode = dom.selectSingleNode("//FromDate/text()"),
    today = new Date();

nNode.data = [today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), today.getFullYear()].join('/') + ' 00:00:00';
dom.save(pathToXML);
```